# How do I fix my bathroom mirror

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm going crazy! This mirror has been broken for ages, I've e-mailed the landlord about it multiple times, but they keep telling me off.

However, when I took a quick sneak peak at their reception computer, they have an e-mail sitting in their inbox from the mirror supplier asking them to come pick it up since it's been waiting for over a month.

How do I get them to fix my mirror?

Comment: If the mirror was fixable, it would be in the objectives list.

Comment: +1 - Am I the only one here who sees Konerak is trolling? ;)

Comment: You just accidentally the game.

Comment: Come on guys, don't feed the trolls

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're not supposed to actually fix it.

The point of the broken mirror is it adds a bit of depth to your character - he keeps breaking it because he can't stand to look at himself.

Comment: Holy carp, that didn't even occur to me. That's cool.

Comment: I didn't think of it that way. That is really cool.

Comment: Guys, seriously ?

Comment: @Anto I have failed you.

Comment: @Alex [Kinda](http://www.thelifestream.net/forums/images/smilies/TripleFacePalm.jpg)

Comment: There's no evidence to suggest that he broke it multiple times.

Comment: @Brian: Read the emails at the front desk.  One of them says something along the lines of "This is the third mirror this month," or something

Answer (score 13):

Adam broke the mirror because looking in it reminds him of his augmentations, and looking at his augmentations reminds him of his failure to protect Megan. He is not going to fix it.

It has absolutely nothing to do with Eidos Montreal deciding not to program in any reflective surfaces and the complexities therein. ;)

Comment: But it looks as if he's trying to fix it. He put a post-it note on the broken mirror to contact the landlord, he e-mailed reception... it looks like **they** are holding back the new mirror (which is waiting for pickup).

Comment: @Konerak it's not the first mirror he broke, and the landlord probaly thinks he's going to break the new one too.

Comment: Lisa? You mean Megan?

Comment: @BrianGordon Wow, over a year to notice my mistake!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot fix the mirror, it simply adds a story element to the game.

Screenshots of the emails for anyone interested:

Email on Jensen's computer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDLZc.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDLZc.jpg]

Email on lobby computer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC6AQ.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC6AQ.jpg]

Mirror with note:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuTin.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuTin.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

Out of story reason:

Showing a mirror in an FPS requires an extremely high quality of animation for the main character to avoid brekaing immersion; these are animations that normally would never be visible in first person. As such, the dev cost of including a mirror is very high relative to rare occurrences. This is why the mirror is not reflective, even though it's a mirror.

Not only that, the frequent broken and missing mirrors in the game call back to the orignal DX, which featured really terrible mirrors (unsynced images, bad animation). By breaking all the mirrors they could avoid the same thing happening again

Comment: It's true that showing mirrors is hard, but I think I recall several occasions in Deus Ex where it has been done. Maggie Chow's apartment, or various bathrooms (UNATCO, sewers, ...) had mirrors iirc?

Comment: Oops. It did have mirrors, they were just horribly designed. They looked awful and the mirror image actually wasn't synced, and moved slightly after you did.

Answer (score 2):

A far as I can tell from some research, there is no actual way to get the mirror fixed.

Comment: Where is the research?